# Socket.IO blocked by Content Security Policy

Tags: html, node.js, security, socket.io, content-security-policy

I am trying to create a super simple website just to show content and have another page be able to change said content on the page. (Security is of 0 concern so feel free to post really sketchy answers).

But when I visit the site (hosted on a digital ocean server behind NGINX), I get the following error:

```
Refused to connect to wss://subdomain.domain.online/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=SIDHERE because it appears in neither the connect-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

I have looked everywhere and got to this policy of:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' wss: ws: *; connect-src 'self' ws: wss: *;">
```

But still get the error, I was wondering if anyone would know a fix.

Cheers, Sam.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you have [publish 2 CSPs](https://csplite.com/csp282/#fix_presents_in_CSP) - one via `<meta http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy'>` tag and the second one via CSP HTTP header. In this case the most stringent policy apply.

The second CSP is published on server by Helmet middleware, Helmet version 4 have CSP swiched on with default rules.

Disable CSP in `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)` if you wish to use  tag:

```
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: false,
  })
);
```

or [configure](https://helmetjs.github.io/#reference) CSP header in Helmet and do not use meta tag.