# React - Refused to load the script Google Analytics and Stripe scripts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, content-security-policy

After carefully going over a lot of similar issues I still can't find a solution to this CSP violation error. I am using React with Express backend.

I have tried different Content-Security-Policy meta contents, including giving a full permission string but still getting these two errors.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="
      default-src * self blob: data: gap:; 
      style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; 
      script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; 
      object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; 
      img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; 
      connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; 
      frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;">
```

Here are the exact error messages:

- *Refused to load the script 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
- Refused to load the script 'https://js.stripe.com/v3' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.*

And here is the picture: [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJlzu.png)

How this problem can be tackled? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Say "Hello" to Helmet. It [have already published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66418520/socket-io-blocked-by-content-security-policy/66450210#66450210) CSP via HTTP header - `script-src 'self'` it's default Helmet's policy. Therefore you can't relax this CSP with a new one via meta tag. Use either HTTP header or meta tag to delivery Content Security Policy, not the both at once.

Comment: You saved my day man, thank you very much, I appreciate your help!